# Disappearing references replaced with [?] and errors in the bibliography due to style file definition errors

Tags: bibliographies, errors, cross-referencing, missing

**Hi,
This is my first time using LaTeX and Bibtex. This is the link to my document, ;**

[LaTeX file on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/17091288gjcqccwrbkkq#/65201808/)

**It is giving the following error messages;**

```
(no line number):
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: ieeetr.bst
Database file #1: mainNotes.bib
Database file #2: renewables.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 62 of file renewables.bib
 : 
 : @article{majeau2011life,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 401 of file renewables.bib
 : 
 : @article{huijbregts2016recipe,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Illegal end of database file---line 494 of file renewables.bib
 : }
 :  
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "kalbar2017weighting"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "brilhuismeijer2014norm"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "imbeault2013analytical"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "weidema2013overview"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "muller2016application"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "gao2018cross"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "birkeland2011assessing"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ciroth2004uncertainty"
Warning--can't use both volume and number fields in rodriguez2014nanotoxicity
Warning--empty journal in richa2016sustainable
Warning--empty journal in huijbregts2016recipe
You've used 44 entries,
            1876 wiz_defined-function locations,
            731 strings with 12742 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 12090 in all, are:
= -- 1223
> -- 477
< -- 0
+ -- 178
- -- 134
* -- 849
:= -- 1708
add.period$ -- 48
call.type$ -- 44
change.case$ -- 42
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 47
duplicate$ -- 606
empty$ -- 1115
format.name$ -- 134
if$ -- 2940
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 44
missing$ -- 38
newline$ -- 139
num.names$ -- 43
pop$ -- 128
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 436
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 852
swap$ -- 261
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 3
while$ -- 122
width$ -- 46
write$ -- 432
(There were 3 error messages)
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:462:
LaTeX Error:
 Command \bibhang already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.462 \newlength{\bibhang}
```

In the document this is how I wrote the bibliography file;

```
\bibliography{renewables}
```

**This is my bibliography file {renewables.bib};**

```
@article{stenzel2018environmental,
  title={Environmental impacts of electricity generation for Graciosa Island, Azores},
  author={Stenzel, Peter and Schreiber, Andrea and Marx, Josefine and Wulf, Christina and Schreieder, Michael and Stephan, Lars},
  journal={Journal of Energy Storage},
  volume={15},
  pages={292--303},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{ellingsen2017identifying,
  title={Identifying key assumptions and differences in life cycle assessment studies of lithium-ion traction batteries with focus on greenhouse gas emissions},
  author={Ellingsen, Linda Ager-Wick and Hung, Christine Roxanne and Str{\o}mman, Anders Hammer},
  journal={Transportation Research Part D: Transport and Environment},
  volume={55},
  pages={82--90},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{larcher2015towards,
  title={Towards greener and more sustainable batteries for electrical energy storage},
  author={Larcher, Dominique and Tarascon, Jean-Marie},
  journal={Nature chemistry},
  volume={7},
  number={1},
  pages={19},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{banos2011optimization,
  title={Optimization methods applied to renewable and sustainable energy: A review},
  author={Banos, Raul and Manzano-Agugliaro, Francisco and Montoya, FG and Gil, Consolacion and Alcayde, Alfredo and G{\'o}mez, Julio},
  journal={Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
  volume={15},
  number={4},
  pages={1753--1766},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{jacobson2009path,
  title={A path to sustainable energy by 2030},
  author={Jacobson, Mark Z and Delucchi, Mark A},
  journal={Scientific American},
  volume={301},
  number={5},
  pages={58--65},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@misc{southwest2016life,
  author={Southwest Environmental (UK) },
  title={{Life Cycle Assessment} image},
  year={2016},
  howpublished={url{http://www.southwest-environmental.co.uk/further%20info/life_cycle_assessment/life_cycle_assessment_consultants.html},
  urldate={2018-07-06}
}

@article{majeau2011life,
  title={Life cycle environmental assessment of lithium-ion and nickel metal hydride batteries for plug-in hybrid and battery electric vehicles},
  author={Majeau-Bettez, Guillaume and Hawkins, Troy R and Str{\o}mman, Anders Hammer},
  journal={Environmental science \& technology},
  volume={45},
  number={10},
  pages={4548--4554},
  year={2011},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@article{boyden2016environmental,
  title={The environmental impacts of recycling portable lithium-ion batteries},
  author={Boyden, Anna and Soo, Vi Kie and Doolan, Matthew},
  journal={Procedia CIRP},
  volume={48},
  pages={188--193},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@inproceedings{gaines2011life,
  title={Life-cycle analysis for lithium-ion battery production and recycling},
  author={Gaines, Linda and Sullivan, John and Burnham, Andrew and Belharouak, I},
  booktitle={Transportation Research Board 90th Annual Meeting, Washington, DC},
  pages={23--27},
  year={2011}
}

@article{das2018life,
  title={Life cycle energy and carbon footprint analysis of photovoltaic battery microgrid system in India},
  author={Das, Jani and Abraham, Ajit Paul and Ghosh, Prakash C and Banerjee, Rangan},
  journal={Clean Technologies and Environmental Policy},
  volume={20},
  number={1},
  pages={65--80},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{vandepaer2017environmental,
  title={Environmental impacts of Lithium Metal Polymer and Lithium-ion stationary batteries},
  author={Vandepaer, Laurent and Cloutier, Julie and Amor, Ben},
  journal={Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
  volume={78},
  pages={46--60},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@inproceedings{rodriguez2014nanotoxicity,
  title={Nanotoxicity and life cycle assessment: first attempt towards the determination of characterization factors for carbon nanotubes},
  author={Rodriguez-Garcia, Gonzalo and Zimmermann, Benedikt and Weil, Marcel},
  booktitle={IOP Conference Series: Materials Science and Engineering},
  volume={64},
  number={1},
  pages={012029},
  year={2014},
  organization={IOP Publishing}
}

@proceedings{rodriguezpotential,
  title={Potential environmental impacts of Li-ion batteries and supercapacitors: Toxicity of carbon nanotubes},
  author={Rodriguez-Garcia, Gonzalo and Weil, Marcel},
  year={2014}
}


@article{baumann2017co2,
  title={CO2 Footprint and Life-Cycle Costs of Electrochemical Energy Storage for Stationary Grid Applications},
  author={Baumann, M and Peters, JF and Weil, M and Grunwald, A},
  journal={Energy Technology},
  volume={5},
  number={7},
  pages={1071--1083},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{oliveira2015key,
  title={Key issues of lithium-ion batteries--from resource depletion to environmental performance indicators},
  author={Oliveira, Luis and Messagie, Maarten and Rangaraju, Surendraprabu and Sanfelix, Javier and Rivas, Maria Hernandez and Van Mierlo, Joeri},
  journal={Journal of cleaner production},
  volume={108},
  pages={354--362},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@inproceedings{gabbar2007life,
  title={Life Cycle Assessment and Environmental Impact Analysis for green energy production plants},
  author={Gabbar, Hossam A},
  booktitle={Machine Learning and Cybernetics, 2007 International Conference on},
  volume={4},
  pages={2058--2063},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{dunn2012impact,
  title={Impact of recycling on cradle-to-gate energy consumption and greenhouse gas emissions of automotive lithium-ion batteries},
  author={Dunn, Jennifer B and Gaines, Linda and Sullivan, John and Wang, Michael Q},
  journal={Environmental science \& technology},
  volume={46},
  number={22},
  pages={12704--12710},
  year={2012},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@article{gaines2012recycle,
  title={To recycle, or not to recycle, that is the question: Insights from life-cycle analysis},
  author={Gaines, Linda},
  journal={MRS bulletin},
  volume={37},
  number={4},
  pages={333--338},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}

@article{gaines2014future,
  title={The future of automotive lithium-ion battery recycling: Charting a sustainable course},
  author={Gaines, Linda},
  journal={Sustainable Materials and Technologies},
  volume={1},
  pages={2--7},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{doi:10.1021/es903729a,
author = {Notter, Dominic A. and Gauch, Marcel and Widmer, Rolf and Wäger, Patrick and Stamp, Anna and Zah, Rainer and Althaus, Hans-Jörg},
title = {Contribution of Li-Ion Batteries to the Environmental Impact of Electric Vehicles},
journal = {Environmental Science \& Technology},
volume = {44},
number = {17},
pages = {6550-6556},
year = {2010},
doi = {10.1021/es903729a},
    note ={PMID: 20695466},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1021/es903729a},
eprint = {https://doi.org/10.1021/es903729a}
}

@article{peters2017aqueous,
  title={Aqueous hybrid ion batteries--An environmentally friendly alternative for stationary energy storage?},
  author={Peters, Jens F and Weil, Marcel},
  journal={Journal of Power Sources},
  volume={364},
  pages={258--265},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{peters2018providing,
  title={Providing a common base for life cycle assessments of Li-Ion batteries},
  author={Peters, Jens F and Weil, Marcel},
  journal={Journal of Cleaner Production},
  volume={171},
  pages={704--713},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{peters2017environmental,
  title={The environmental impact of Li-Ion batteries and the role of key parameters--A review},
  author={Peters, Jens F and Baumann, Manuel and Zimmermann, Benedikt and Braun, Jessica and Weil, Marcel},
  journal={Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
  volume={67},
  pages={491--506},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{unterreiner2016recycling,
  title={Recycling of Battery Technologies--Ecological Impact Analysis Using Life Cycle Assessment (LCA)},
  author={Unterreiner, Lea and J{\"u}lch, Verena and Reith, S{\"o}ren},
  journal={Energy Procedia},
  volume={99},
  pages={229--234},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{liang2017life,
  title={Life cycle assessment of lithium-ion batteries for greenhouse gas emissions},
  author={Liang, Yuhan and Su, Jing and Xi, Beidou and Yu, Yajuan and Ji, Danfeng and Sun, Yuanyuan and Cui, Chifei and Zhu, Jianchao},
  journal={Resources, Conservation and Recycling},
  volume={117},
  pages={285--293},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{hiremath2015comparative,
  title={Comparative life cycle assessment of battery storage systems for stationary applications},
  author={Hiremath, Mitavachan and Derendorf, Karen and Vogt, Thomas},
  journal={Environmental science \& technology},
  volume={49},
  number={8},
  pages={4825--4833},
  year={2015},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@article{fthenakis2011methodology,
  title={Methodology guidelines on life cycle assessment of photovoltaic electricity},
  author={Fthenakis, Vasilis and Frischknecht, Rolf and Raugei, Marco and Kim, H Chul and Alsema, Erik and Held, Michael and de Wild-Scholten, Mariska},
  journal={IEA PVPS Task},
  volume={12},
  year={2011}
}

@article{shirley2015energy,
  title={Energy planning and development in Malaysian Borneo: Assessing the benefits of distributed technologies versus large scale energy mega-projects},
  author={Shirley, Rebekah and Kammen, Daniel},
  journal={Energy Strategy Reviews},
  volume={8},
  pages={15--29},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@mastersthesis{wong2013off,
    author={Wong, Sze Yie and others},
    title={{An off-grid solar system for rural village implementation in East Malaysia}},
    school={Swinburne University of Technology},
    address={Malaysia},
    year={2013}
}

@book{international2006environmentalpf,
  title={Environmental Management: Life Cycle Assessment; Principles and Framework},
  author={International Organization for Standardization},
  year={2006},
  publisher={ISO}
}

@book{international2006environmentalrg,
  title={Environmental Management: Life Cycle Assessments: Requirements and Guidelines},
  author={International Standardization Organization},
  year={2006},
  publisher={ISO}
}

@mastersthesis{hiremath2014comparative,
   author={Hiremath, Mitavachan and Siebenhuener, Bernd and Vogt, Thomas and Heinemann, Detlev},
   title={Comparative Life Cycle Assessment of Stationary Battery Storage Technologies for Balancing Fluctuations of Renewable Energy Sources},
   school={University of Oldenburg},
   address={Germany},
  year={2014}
}

@mastersthesis{ahmadi2014cascaded,
  title={Cascaded Use and Sustainable Management of Lithium-ion Batteries in Mobility and Stationary Power},
  author={Ahmadi, Leila},
  year={2014},
  school={University of Waterloo}
}

@article{richa2016sustainable,
  title={Sustainable management of lithium-ion batteries after use in electric vehicles},
  author={Richa, Kirti},
  year={2016}
}

@article{jungbluth2005life,
  title={Life cycle assessment of crystalline photovoltaics in the Swiss ecoinvent database},
  author={Jungbluth, Niels},
  journal={Progress in Photovoltaics: Research and Applications},
  volume={13},
  number={5},
  pages={429--446},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@incollection{fthenakis2017environmental,
  title={Environmental life-cycle assessment of photovoltaic systems},
  author={Fthenakis, V and Raugei, M},
  booktitle={The Performance of Photovoltaic (PV) System},
  pages={209--232},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{fthenakis2008emissions,
  title={Emissions from photovoltaic life cycles},
  author={Fthenakis, Vasilis M and Kim, Hyung Chul and Alsema, Erik},
  journal={Environmental science \& technology},
  volume={42},
  number={6},
  pages={2168--2174},
  year={2008},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@article{alsema2005environmental,
  title={Environmental impact of crystalline silicon photovoltaic module production},
  author={Alsema, Erik and de Wild, Mariska J},
  journal={MRS Online Proceedings Library Archive},
  volume={895},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}

@techreport{atkinson2018batang,
     title={{Batang Ai CSR Solar: Iban Longhouse Solar Home System Data Collection (Data Provided from Sarawak Energy Sdn. Bhd. Renewable Energy R&D for educational purposes)}},
     author={Atkinson Ronifield and Thomas Bocek and Fabio Hecht and Guilherme Machado and Peter Racz and Martin Waldburger},
     group={csg},
     year={2018},
     institution={Sarawak Energy Berhad}
}

@techreport{wambach2018life,
     title={{Life Cycle Inventory of Current Photovoltaic Module Recycling Processes in Europe (IEA PVPS Task12, Subtask 2, LCA
Report IEA-PVPS T12-12:2017)}},
     author={Karsten Wambach},
     group={csg},
     year={2018},
     institution={International Energy Agency}
}

@book{samantara2017materials,
  title={Materials Development for Active/Passive Components of a Supercapacitor: Background, Present Status and Future Perspective},
  author={Samantara, Aneeya K and Ratha, Satyajit},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@misc{mouser2018supercap,
  author={Mouser Electronics },
  title={{BMOD0165 P048 B01 Maxwell Technologies | Mouser} catalog},
  year=2018,
  howpublished={\url{https://my.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Maxwell-Technologies/BMOD0165-P048-B01?qs=oFx6pF86PmDnxnYMFiy63g==},
  urldate={2018-06-09}
}

@article{huijbregts2016recipe,
  title={ReCiPe 2016: A harmonized life cycle impact assessment method at midpoint and endpoint level Report I: Characterization},
  author={Huijbregts, MAJ and Steinmann, ZJN and Elshout, PMF and Stam, G and Verones, F and Vieira, MDM and Hollander, A and Zijp, M and van Zelm, R},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Rijksinstituut voor Volksgezondheid en Milieu RIVM}
}

@misc{ponsioen2014norm,
  author={Tommie Ponsioen},
  title={{The Normalisation Step in LCIA | PRé Sustainability} article},
  year=2014,
  howpublished={\url{{https://www.pre-sustainability.com/news/the-normalisation-step-in-lcia},
  urldate={2018-07-21}
}

@misc{brilhuismeijer2014norm,
  author={Ellen Brilhuis-Meijer},
  title={{Weighting: Applying a Value Judgement to LCA Results} article},
  year=2014,
  howpublished={\url{https://www.pre-sustainability.com/news/weighting-applying-a-value-judgement-to-lca-results/},
  urldate={2018-07-21}
}

@article{kalbar2017weighting,
  title={Weighting and Aggregation in Life Cycle Assessment: Do Present Aggregated Single Scores Provide Correct Decision Support?},
  author={Kalbar, Pradip P and Birkved, Morten and Nygaard, Simon Elsborg and Hauschild, Michael},
  journal={Journal of Industrial Ecology},
  volume={21},
  number={6},
  pages={1591--1600},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{imbeault2013analytical,
  title={Analytical propagation of uncertainty in life cycle assessment using matrix formulation},
  author={Imbeault-T{\'e}treault, Hugues and Jolliet, Olivier and Desch{\^e}nes, Louise and Rosenbaum, Ralph K},
  journal={Journal of Industrial Ecology},
  volume={17},
  number={4},
  pages={485--492},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{weidema2013overview,
  title={Overview and methodology: Data quality guideline for the ecoinvent database version 3},
  author={Weidema, Bo Pedersen and Bauer, Ch and Hischier, Roland and Mutel, Christopher and Nemecek, Thomas and Reinhard, J and Vadenbo, CO and Wernet, Gregor},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Swiss Centre for Life Cycle Inventories}
}

@article{muller2016application,
  title={The application of the pedigree approach to the distributions foreseen in ecoinvent v3},
  author={Muller, St{\'e}phanie and Lesage, Pascal and Ciroth, Andreas and Mutel, Christopher and Weidema, Bo P and Samson, R{\'e}jean},
  journal={The International Journal of Life Cycle Assessment},
  volume={21},
  number={9},
  pages={1327--1337},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{gao2018cross,
  title={A cross-disciplinary overview of naturally derived materials for electrochemical energy storage},
  author={Gao, Mengyao and Pan, Shu-Yuan and Chen, Wen-Chang and Chiang, Pen-Chi},
  journal={Materials Today Energy},
  volume={7},
  pages={58--79},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@mastersthesis{birkeland2011assessing,
    author    = {Birkeland, Christine},
    title     = {Assessing the life cycle environmental impacts of offshore wind power generation and power transmission in the North Sea},
    school    = {Norwegian Institute of Science and Technology},
    %type     = {Masters thesis},
    %address  = "Norway",
    year      = "{2011}",
    %month    = "June",
    %note     = "https://daim.idi.ntnu.no/masteroppgaver/006/6222/masteroppgave.pdf",
}

@article{ciroth2004uncertainty,
  title={Uncertainty calculation in life cycle assessments},
  author={Ciroth, Andreas and Fleischer, G{\"u}nter and Steinbach, J{\"o}rg},
  journal={The International Journal of Life Cycle Assessment},
  volume={9},
  number={4},
  pages={216},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

**Today is my deadline so I am a bit worried as my trial and error method is not working out. Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you for your time!**

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please expand your code to a full  minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)). A small part and the ending with `\end{document}` is missing.

Comment: Maybe you mean `@misc` instead of `@wmisc`?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but please don't load the same packages multiple times.

Comment: if bibtex can not make your bibliography then latex will show `?` for the references so that is expected. But it is hard to say what is wrong with your bib file as (apart from the `@wmisc`) you have not shown the part of the file that corresponds to the errors.

Comment: unrelated to bibtex but you almost certainly want to load `graphicx` and not load `graphics` or `epsf`  for image inclusion.

Comment: Thank you @Bobyandbob, good to be part of this community! Should I upload the entire code of the main.tex and renewables.bib? Sorry if this is something basic, its my first time using LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle I've corrected it according to your advice and added the complete bib file. Would appreciate your advice very much as my deadline is in a few hours.

Comment: @Ayesha not all. Only one important fact: We need minimal code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Thats it. I hope David solved your problem.

Comment: @Bobyandbob thank you! I've put up the link to my LaTeX file as the entire code is larger than the number of allowed characters. Could you please advise on how I can rectify the errors and make the references appear? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle I've corrected the wmisc and Marcel with a comma. However for the other 3 errors I'm sorry I wasn't able to understand where they need a , or bracket. Could you kindly clarify? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Ayeshaline 401 error is because of `howpublished={\url{https://my.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Maxwell-Technologies/BMOD0165-P048-B01?qs=oFx6pF86PmDnxnYMFiy63g==},`  it needs `}}` not `}` at the end as you have `{\url{` at the start.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle I have changed the code as you have written it out. And made similar changes to the other references. However, I am still experiencing errors. Could you please take a look at https://www.overleaf.com/17091288gjcqccwrbkkq#/65201808/ ? I'm not sure of what to do now. Your advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: `I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux` you need `\bibliographystyle{natplain}` or some such style

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle thank you so much for the natplain advice. There are no red error messages now. However, it is still saying " I couldn't open style file natplain.bst
---line 131 of file main.aux
 : \bibstyle{natplain
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file main.aux "  What can I do for this please? Please assist me, it is now an hour to my deadline, and the missing references are the only thing standing in the way of the submission. Thank you

Comment: sorry typo:  the style is called `plainnat` not `natplain`

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle thank you, just corrected. It is showing a red warning as follows; I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
You've used 52 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,   How can I address this to show the missing references please?

Comment: @samcarter could you please help me? I have a small window of time before I need to submit.My references are missing and even after changing the package and addressing the errors mentioned I am unable to see them.  https://www.overleaf.com/17091288gjcqccwrbkkq#/65201808/

Comment: @Ayesha There are still several issues: as @ DavidCarlisle said in his comment above, it should be `plainnat` and not `natplain`. `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` has to be after `\begin{document}`, you cannot use `%` to comment out fields in bibtex, if you don't want a note field to be displayed deleting it is the easiest fix, there are several missing `}` at the end of `howpublished` fields and `\url` should only be followed by one opening `{`, not two.

Comment: Also add the end of entries, there should only be one `}`, not `}}`

Answer (score 3):

The error messages are (for bibtex) quite clear

```
Warning--entry type for "southwest2016life" isn't style-file defined
--line 54 of file renewables.bib
```

line 54 has

```
@wmisc{southwest2016life,
```

which should be

```
@misc{southwest2016life,
```

then

```
: @article{majeau2011life,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 126 of file renewables.bib
```

at line 125-126 there is

```
  author={Rodriguez-Garcia, Gonzalo and Weil, Marcel}
  year={2014}
```

which as the error says is missing a `,` after `Marcel}`

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle  I've corrected the wmisc and Marcel with a comma. However for the other 3 errors I'm sorry I wasn't able to understand where they need a , or bracket. Could you kindly clarify? Thank you for your time!